# jQuery ui tabs: all tabs show same content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jsp, tabs

I'm following the simple example posted in jQuery-ui web page to implement some tabs, but I have the problem that all 3 divs content are shown on each of the 3 tabs to display (the only thing shown properly are the tab's names). The full JSP/HTML code from my page is this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>

    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="<c:url value="/css/main_style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<c:url value="/css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="<c:url value="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Main window</title>
        <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WR">

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="a_image"><img src = "images/a.png"></div>
            <div id="webapp_name"> dcdfsadfsadfsa </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div id="mainframe"> -->
        <div id="buttons">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="MainView/report/instant"><img src = "images/instant_icon.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="MainView/report/datagap"><img src = "images/datagap_icon.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="MainView/report/integrity"><img src = "images/integrity_icon.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="MainView/report/logbook"><img src = "images/logbook_icon.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs2">Proind dolor iee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#chartSummary">Summary</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs2">
                    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs3">
                    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
                    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="chartSummary">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${numGraficos}">
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${i % 3 == 0}">
                                        <td><img src="chart/${i}"></td></tr>
                                        </c:when>
                                        <c:otherwise>
                                    <td><img src="chart/${i}"></td>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody have a clue about this issue?

Comment: show only relevant html rendered code, not all the code you use server side

Comment: plese make fiddles using jsfiddle.net

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't have jquery-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem myself. There is a specific tutorial for this issue in this [link](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/02/17/using-jquery-ui-tabs-with-the-base-tag/)

I just specified the URL that each tab has to follow. In my case, the right code is:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="MainView/report/datagap/result#tabs2">Proind dolor iee</a></li>
    <li><a href="MainView/report/datagap/result#tabs3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    <li><a href="MainView/report/datagap/result#chartSummary">Summary</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps to anybody!!

Answer (score 0):

Here a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebdyt/). Looks like you have missed the css file. I added the following css to fiddle.

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I see in your Fiddle works, but still not working for me. I have revised all files (images, css, js, etc...), html syntax, removed some parts of the code, and even reduce the whole page to the "tabs" example in jQuery page, and still doesn't work...

Comment: <td><img src="chart/${i}"></td></tr>  The last </tr> tag.. where's the open tag for it..? or is it just a typo error?

Comment: Yes, I know there are some HTML errors in the code I posted. However, I've removed the whole <table> tag, and everything inside it, and keeps showing the same content in all three tabs...

Comment: Hey, I found the error. I was able to see with Firebug that the GET request when clicking on a tab was throwing an error. It looks like this line `<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WR">` is the source of the error. However, I cannot remove it. If I do it, tabs works, but all images and other references to local files break. How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no error, except from the typical "GET error: Resource not found". If I remove that line the whole Spring context changes, and that forces me to apply a url change in all my reference lines of code. Would be great if jQuery-tabs accepted a param to set the base context on which to throw the GET requests. Is this possible?