# UI tabs page showing all content at once

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I tried what was mentioned here [jQuery ui tabs: all tabs show same content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488478/jquery-ui-tabs-all-tabs-show-same-content), but I just can't figure out what is wrong.

I have the tabs UI working fine locally, but can't get it to work online.

Any suggestions?

This is the page I'm trying to get it to work on.

http://www.connect4webdesign.com/test/

Comment: Learn to use your browser’s error console …

Comment: I'm wondering if this loading on line 89 is messing things up.  I can't figure out where its loading from.  I think some pluging must be loading it??                                  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>

Answer (score 0):

Colorbox.js is breaking your page.

it's a .js file, do not include  tags in the document.

Comment: I removed the script tags, but still no luck.  I do feel like something else is breaking it because it worked fine locally.